# EAI Siebel Adapter - Account with Address Insert Issue

Tags: insert, siebel, eai

I am using EAI Siebel Adapter to Insert an Account record. The setup in our system is such that both Contact & Address (MVG) are mandatory hence the Account record cannot be committed without entering the same.

I have created an IO having Account as Parent and Account_Business Address & Account_Primary Contact as child Assoc MVG BusComps as I have to set Primary also during insert.

Since 'Street Address' the MVG field inside Account BC is marked as mandatory, during setfield value of the other Account fields in the EAI process 'Street Address is a required field' error (SBL-DAT-00498)(SBL-EAI-04389) appears.

If I add the field 'Street Address' into the 'Account' IC with 'City' & 'Address', system tries to create a New Address record and if the same already exists 'Address Name already exists' error (SBL-EAI-04381) is seen.

I am new to EAI concepts and hence unable to proceed or debug. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At both of the Address Integration components, try giving IC User properties

Name: MVGAssociation
,
Value: Y

and another one

Name: MVGLink
,
Value: Business Address

This should tell the IO to associate the address if it is already present.

There are a lot of vanilla integration objects where they have multiple address levels, and cloning one of them or using them is Siebel best practice.

For example, please check vanilla integation object:  "Base Account".

If these changes still does not work, then its best you extract the SQL for this insertion from the EAI component logs.

Comment: The IC User properties are already present as the IO was created using wizard. The Vanilla IO's are not helpful as 'Street Address' has been made mandatory as a customization for clients need.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing these kinds of requirements, which in my experience are ever expanding, are best to be implemented using a workflow approach. This also provides a better platform for future enhancements.

This way you also have more control over what to do next in case of missing or malformed data. I.e. what kind of error to return, or to create the Account and then an Employee activity to be picked up for manual processing.